# Bootstrap change two carousel with one carousel indicators

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have two carousel. One of them has a carousel indicators. what i want to do is change the two carousel's when i press this.

My first carousel

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel carousel2" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/example1.png" alt="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/example2.png" alt="example2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My second carousel with carousel indicators

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/example1.png" alt="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/example2.png" alt="example2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I preferred small images to make the sliders visible. That's why I made the white **indicators red**.

There are also two code snippets so you can compare the **old and new version**.

#### New version

```js
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
   $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel(e.to);
})
```

```css
.carousel-indicators li {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel carousel2" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/40" alt="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/41" alt="example2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/42" alt="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/43" alt="example2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Normal version

```css
.carousel-indicators li {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel carousel2" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/40" alt="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/41" alt="example2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/42" alt="example1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/120/43" alt="example2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```